# C++: overriding pure virtual member variable?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, oop, virtual

This question is best described in code.  I have a class called `Vertex` that contains an instance of a class called `Params`:

```
class Params {
    virtual Params operator + (Params const& p) = 0;
};

class Vertex {
    public:
        Params operator + (Params const& ap) const {
            return p + ap
        };

        virtual float eval() = 0;

    private:
        Params const p;
};
```

I also have a class called `EllParams` which is derived from `Params` and `EllVertex` which is derived from `Vertex`.  What I'm wondering is how to deal with the private member variable `p` in `Vertex` in `EllVertex`: I want it to be of type `EllParams`.  Is there some way of making `p` virtual/overriding it?  Or should I look to templates for a solution?

Comment: There's no way to make data members 'virtual'. I would try to avoid data members in the non-leaf classes of your inheritance tree; if you need access to a data member from a base class then make a virtual function that can be implemented in the derived class.

Comment: You're trying to use a data member of an abstract type.  That doesn't work.  Use a pointer instead (you may want to use a smart pointer).  That way, the virtual behavior will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...you need to initialize the `Params` in `Vertex` somehow. So make it a parameter on the `Vertex` constructor. Then your `EllVertex` will pass an `EllParams` to the parent constructor from its constructor and that will be how the private `Vertex.p` is initialized.

For example:

```
class Params {
    virtual Params operator + (Params const& p) = 0;
};

class Vertex {
    public:
        Params operator + (Params const& ap) const {
            return *p + ap
        };

        virtual float eval() = 0;

    protected:
        Vertex(Params* inputParams) : p(inputParams) {}

    private:
        Params* const p;
};
```

Notice that I have changed your `p` member variable to a pointer. That way, you don't have to ensure that a correct copy constructor is defined for `Params` or any subclasses.